# Python read html table from confluence and print each row as list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'd like to parse confuence page ,read table and create list for each row.

My Table looks like

[image]

My code

```
x = confluence.get_page_by_id(p_id,expand="body.storage")

soup = BeautifulSoup(x["body"]["storage"]["value"], 'html.parser')

for tables in soup.select("table tr"):
    data = [item.get_text() for item in tables.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

But problem is, second column becuase of the new lines output of the code

```
['Karnataka','Bangalore','BangaloreMysoreTumkur']
```

And I want the output ot look like

```
['Karnataka','Bangalore','Bangalore Mysore Tumkur']
```

Can you please provide the code to fix this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup removes the whitespace in rendered HTML, to use a custom separator use this:

```
data = [item.get_text(separator=" ") for item in tables.select("td")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of missing HTML example as text, I am not aware of the contents, but you could try to set join parmeter for [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
item.get_text(' ')
```